# Get Associated product By ID

Tags: magento-1.8, collection-filtering, associate-products

Hi I'm using below code to fetch associated product list

```
$associated_products = $_product->loadByAttribute('sku', $_product->getSku())->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();
```

Is there any way to pass entity_id and fetch product belongs to that particular `entity_id` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$associated_products = $_product->load($_product->getId())->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();
```

or if you already have the `$_product` entity, no need to load it again.
Try this:

```
$associated_products = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts();
```

Comment: does it not depend on wether you are using configurable or groupped products? (I was thinking about `getUsedProducts()` and `getAssociatedProducts()`

Comment: I thought it was only for configurable. I could be wrong.

Comment: @marius I'm getting the same associated product collections. I'm trying to get only one associated product by passing it's id.

Comment: @VinothPandiyan Then just user: `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('your id here');` Is that what you need? Your question seams unclear.

Comment: @Marius I can confirm that `getAssociatedProducts()` => grouped products and `getUsedProducts()` => configurable products